# If I want to control the mouse cursor using Python, should I look into docs for GNOME or X?

Tags: gnome, xorg, python, cursor

I want to write a program in Python runs on Ubuntu and moves the mouse cursor, just like a hardware mouse would.  What should I try to connect to: X or GNOME?  I am pretty sure that X would work, but I have heard that it is very low-level and difficult to use.  Is there some sort of GNOME API for this sort of thing, or would I have to build my own version of GNOME with some added changes?  Would it just be easier to emulate a mouse?  Are any of these things possible?

Comment: what is the purpose for controlling the mouse cursor? Do you want to control it inside your application or do you need your app to run in the background and control the mouse? Please explain your use case and goal so we can suggest solutions. I dont think what you are trying to do is hard at all, but we need more information.

Comment: I once tried to make a GTK+ app to record/replay events, and one thing I ran across was Xtest (from the X libs). Though I never found any decent documentation on it.

Comment: It's a standard part of the X libs that allows you to move the mouse, press keyboard keys, etc. Basically emulate all user input... supposedly. I never could figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example using Xlib via ctypes.cdll in this [ubuntuforums.org thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=5365202). The sequence of calls is LoadLibrary, XOpenDisplay, XDefaultRootWindow, XWarpPointer, XCloseDisplay.

Comment: But does this mean that it is impossible to control the mouse in GNOME or just harder/easier?

Comment: More complex, I think. See for yourself: [the GTK+ source code](http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php) includes [a drag-and-drop test program](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk%2B/tree/tests/testdnd.c) within which you can manually perform a drag-and-drop. You can observe how your arrow key presses move the cursor by means of `gdk_device_warp` calls while your drag-and-drop motion is in progress. Specifically that is the [gdk_device_warp call in gtk_drag_key_cb](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkdnd.c#n4405).